# Generate a patch from svn histroy for a non svn target

Tags: svn

So I'm having to do some large updates to a live system from our svn repository, there is no svn on the target box and no possibility of getting it on.

These updates may span 50+ revisions/files from multiple svn users.

Is there any application that can generate a tree structured output of updated files from a selection of revisions?
Hopefully this would then allow me to upload and copy/paste to update the live box.
A generated txt file with compilation of history would be great as well.

To clarify here is an example;

History;

2202    5/16/11 5:38 PM 1   andymain
Synopsis popup: updated to open portfolio link in new window 
/webportal/portalInclude/portalFields.php

2201    5/16/11 5:07 PM 1   andymain
Updated enquiry from with thank you message. 
/webportal/customers/portalModules/Register/enquiry.php

Desired output;

patch/webportal/customers/portalModules/Register/enquiry.php
patch/webportal/portalInclude/portalFields.php
patch/compiled_history.txt

So is there an application or technique to generate this kind of patch, or is there a better way I'm not aware of?

Cheers Andy

Answer (score 1):

You may use `--summarize` option of `svn diff` showing you the list of files changed between 2 revisions

```
$ svn diff -r 185:194 --summarize
```

Sample result:

```
M       patch/compiled_history.txt
M       patch/webportal/portalInclude/portalFields.php
M       patch/webportal/customers/portalModules/Register/enquiry.php
```

`svn log -v -r 185:195` will show you separately the changes for every revision between the two given revisions

Comment: OK so its command line which I was hoping to avoid, however I  could use the results of the svn diff and pipe to cp to create a patch tree.  I'm not sure of the exact command maybe something like `$ svn diff -r 185:194 --summarize | cp ~/projectname/patch185-194/`  Anyone got the exact command or any thoughts on windows apps or eclipse plugins that can do this?